# Можно ли в ios приложении сделать авторизацию в Firebase Firestore Database, не по email?

Tags: ios, firebase

Вопрос такой. Допустим есть некое ios приложение для небольшой организации и нужно сделать так чтоб сотрудники скачав это приложение, смогли авторизоваться по выданному Логину и Паролю от администратора, самой регистрации нет, то есть никто из посторонних не сможет войти в приложение. Так вот можно ли сделать в Firestore Database это?